# How do I convert a multi dimensional JSON object into javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
[{"tabname":"orders","datagroups":[{"dataname":"ordersToday","datavalue":9},{"dataname":"orders30Days","datavalue":126}]}]
```

When I use `console.log($.parseJSON(thedata))`
I just get the word `Object` and no actual data.

How do I organise this data into a multidimensional javascript array? so that it looks something like this:

```
array("tabname"=>"orders", "datagroup"=>array(array("dataname"=>"ordersToday", "datavalue"=>9),array("dataname"=>"orders30Days","datavalue"=>126)))
```

Comment: Click on the word `Object` in the console to see what it contains. Or do a  `console.log(JSON.stringify(parsedData))`

Comment: Try `console.dir()` instead.

Comment: Clicking on Object gives this: [Object]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
concat: function concat() { [native code] }
constructor: function Array() { [native code] }
every: function every() { [native code] }
filter: function filter() { [native code] }
forEach: function forEach() { [native code] }
indexOf: function indexOf() { [native code] }
join: function join() { [native code] }
lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf() { [native code] }
length: 0
map: function map() { [native code] }
pop: function pop() { [native code] }
push: function push() { [native code] }
..plus plenty more of the same

Comment: console.dir() give me the original json data. I'm trying to have it converted to a javascript array

Comment: It *is* an array already. You only don't get the console printout. If you expand the `0` property you will see an object, if you expand that one's `datagroups` property you will get the inner arrayà

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the long run ?

Comment: To have an array similar to that described at the end of the question so that I can write functions to cycle through it and perform specific tasks on different levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for contributing. I took a break then came back and figured it out. The way my brain works is all wrong.

To access the individual values, I needed to do something like this:

```
var orderStats = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(orderStats[0].datagroups[0].dataname);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an array:

```
var json = '[{"tabname":"orders","datagroups":[{"dataname":"ordersToday","datavalue":9},{"dataname":"orders30Days","datavalue":126}]}]';

var obj = $.parseJSON(json);

Array.isArray(obj) // => true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, really.
You can simply use jQuery's `$.parseJSON (jsonString)`.