# how to convert json array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have below json array

```
`[{"name":"The Shawshank Redemption","rating":"9.3","year":"1994","stars":["Tim Robbins","Morgan Freeman","Bob Gunton"],},{"name":"The Godfather","rating":"9.2","year":"1972","stars":["Marlon Brando","Al Pacino","James Caan"]}]`
```

I want to convert in javascript array and print as html. then I would copy the array and save in .js file like below. problem is how to remove the inverted coma from "name" to name

```
var Movies =  [ { name: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
rating: '9.3',
year: '1994',
stars:
 [ 'Tim Robbins',
   'Morgan Freeman',
   'Bob Gunton' ]},
{ name: 'The Godfather',
rating: '9.2',
year: '1972',
stars:
 [ 'Marlon Brando',
   'Al Pacino',
   'James Caan' ]}
];
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490267/how-do-i-convert-a-multi-dimensional-json-object-into-javascript-array

Comment: But I how would I print this array

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var movies= $.parseJSON(myStr); put your string in it
```

for printing

```
var newAry=[];
$.each(movies,function(i,v){
  newAry.push(JSON.stringify(v));
});

$( '#div' ).html(newAry);
```

Comment: how can i print array on html page, actually i want to save this converted array on seperate js file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pretty print this array, e.g. into a `<pre>` container, you could use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with both parameters:

```
// assuming your parsed JSON is in this variable
var yourObj = JSON.parse( "[your JSON in here]" );

// pretty print
var pretty = JSON.stringify( yourObj, null, '  ' );
document.getElementById( 'target' ).innerHTML = pretty;
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean :

```
var a = [];
a.push($.parseJSON('{"a":"b"}'));
```

?

Answer (score 0):

well, I think above json array is not in proper JSON structure.
first we need to remove comma (,) from 120th index of your json array..
Now it will appear like this..

```
 var jsonArray = `[{"name":"The Shawshank Redemption","rating":"9.3","year":"1994","stars":["Tim Robbins","Morgan Freeman","Bob Gunton"]},{"name":"The Godfather","rating":"9.2","year":"1972","stars":["Marlon Brando","Al Pacino","James Caan"]}]` ;
```

now use json.parse()

i.e

```
var Movies = JSON && JSON.parse(jsonArray);
```

hope this will help you..